# finding a tight scaling bound (in terms of the Big-O notation) of a function of an infinite sum of $1/n^2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, summation, asymptotics, upper-lower-bounds

I have a real-valued function $f(x)=\sum_{n=x+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ where $x \in \mathbb{N}$. I want to understand how $f(x)$ scales with respect to $x$.

One thing I tried is as follows: Since it is not hard to see that $f(x) < \frac{1}{x}$ for all $x$, using the [Big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), $f(x) = O\big(\frac{1}{x}\big)$. But when I actually plot the function and use computer program to find coefficients $a,b,c$ of $f(x) = \frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{x^2} + c$ to fit the curve, it actually gives non-zero values (that are significantly greater than $0$) for both $a$ and $b$ (and $c = 0$), indicating that my first bound is not too tight. So, how can one see a tighter scaling bound of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general method is to use the Euler-Maclaurin formula. In your case, you can notice that:
$$
\frac1{n^2}\sim\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1}
$$
so:
$$
\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1{n^2}\sim \sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1{n}-\frac1{n+1}\sim\frac1N
$$
You can then improve incrementally the asymptotic expansion by killing the next leading order term with the appropriate telescoping power series.

For example, since:
$$
\frac1{n^2}-\frac1{n}+\frac1{n+1}\sim \frac{1}{n^3}\sim \frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{2(n+1)^2}
$$
you get:
$$
\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1{n^2}-\frac1N\sim \sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{2(n+1)^2}\sim\frac1{2N^2}\\
\sum_{n=N}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac1N+\frac1{2N^2}+o(N^{-2})
$$

Hope this case.